# How to split a string by multiple separators and store in a list?

Tags: python

Is there a way to split a string by multiple delimiters?

I have a string like: `"(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))"`, and I want to store it into a list like this:

```
['(', 'I', '(', 'J', '(', 'K', 'L', ')', '(', 'M', 'N', ')', ')', '(', 'O', 'P', ')', ')']
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regex: `re.findall`

```
import re
s = "(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))"
re.findall('[\w\(\)]',s)
```

output:

```
['(', 'I', '(', 'J', '(', 'K', 'L', ')', '(', 'M', 'N', ')', ')', '(', 'O', 'P', ')', ')']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))"
list(s.replace(" ", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

```
s = "(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))"
print [i for i in s if i != " "]
```

or

```
mylist = []
for i in s:
    if i != " ":
        mylist.append(i)
print mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list(str)` but you have to remove the white spaces first:

```
>>> st="(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))"
>>> list(st.replace(' ',''))
['(', 'I', '(', 'J', '(', 'K', 'L', ')', '(', 'M', 'N', ')', ')', '(', 'O', 'P', ')', ')']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
>>> s = "(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))"
>>> [i for i in s if i != ' ']
['(', 'I', '(', 'J', '(', 'K', 'L', ')', '(', 'M', 'N', ')', ')', '(', 'O', 'P', ')', ')']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string = '(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))'

>>> string

'(I (J (K L) (M N)) (O P))'

>>> lst = []

>>>   for x in string:
...    if x != ' ':
...      if lst.append(x)

['(', 'I', '(', 'J', '(', 'K', 'L', ')', '(', 'M', 'N', ')', ')', '(', 'O', 'P', ')', ')']
```